# Email Signature in Salesforce as image

Tags: email

I have a requirements that I want to add Email Signature as image in mail. I have added my signature in 'My Email settings'. While sending email from opportunity I can see my image as signature but when I receive mail that image is not populating properly. Please find below signature task and let me know am I doing correct?
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Can you check the email, if you find the options to download the images.

Comment: Not able to download. When I try to save error is throwing (There was an error saving the file.)